Microsoft Entra Id authentication with PassportJs
I have a website whereby I wish to authenticate users with Microsoft Entra Id (formerly Azure Ad)
However, I've found that the "out of the box" way that Entry Id authenticates is a bit jarring in that it opens a popup window, and has some redirection to a Microsoft domain, and then back to my website.
This is the library that I'm using to achieve this authentication:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-browser
I would strongly prefer to have a simple, embedded login (username, password, submit button) which is fully enclosed by my website's template. When I click "submit", I would call some API service on my back-end to authenticate with Entra Id, and then return an auth token back to my front-end (which is ReactJs, but I don't think that's important).
In other words, I'm hoping to have my login form fully embedded within my site, and without the extra redirections.
I was thinking that using PassportJs with some Entra Id package might achieve this. Here are some libraries that I found:
https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-azure-ad/
https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-azure-ad-oauth2/
I was wondering (before I dig too deep into an implementation!) if anyone knows if what I'm trying to do is even possible.
In other words:

Front-end, using PassportJs, calls some sort of /login or /register endpoint to my API backend
Back-end (nodejs) authenticates the user with Entra Id using some sort of PassportJs package
Front-end receives an auth token from the back-end, which is then passed as Bearer token in subsequent API calls

If it's not possible using the libraries that I've linked to above, is there some other way that I might achieve this.
It's a "hard requirement" that Entra Id is used on the back-end, so there is no getting around that.

What I basically understand is that you want to avoid redirection to Microsoft. To do so, you need to make a few changes in your account. Check the following official article -->https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1517432/how-to-stop-auto-redirect-to-login-microsoft-after

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. Can you [edit] your answer to summarize the relevant guidance from the link? Answers on Stack Overflow can certainly link to additional information, but they should stand on their own even if the page they are linking to is later (re)moved. This is important because often, over time, the linked pages are no longer available, which is frustrating for future members of the community.
